# AMD freeze when playing: amdgpu ERROR Failed to initialize parser

Tags: 22.04, games, freeze, radeon, amdgpu

I randomly get freezes when playing Valheim on Ubuntu 22.04.

journalctl says:

```
Aug 02 22:49:38 myworkstation systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Aug 02 22:49:38 myworkstation systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 02 22:49:38 myworkstation systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Aug 02 22:49:40 myworkstation dbus-daemon[1210]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.75' (uid=0 pid=1259 comm="/usr/lib/snapd/snapd >
Aug 02 22:49:40 myworkstation systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Aug 02 22:49:40 myworkstation dbus-daemon[1210]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Aug 02 22:49:40 myworkstation systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Aug 02 22:49:42 myworkstation gnome-shell[3946]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
Aug 02 22:49:46 myworkstation kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
Aug 02 22:49:51 myworkstation kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
Aug 02 22:49:51 myworkstation kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=111395, emitted seq=111397
Aug 02 22:49:51 myworkstation kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process valheim.x86_64 pid 7270 thread valheim.x86_64 pid 7270
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: amdgpu: cp is busy, skip halt cp
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: amdgpu: rlc is busy, skip halt rlc
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F4007E9000).
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: [drm] VRAM is lost due to GPU reset!
Aug 02 22:49:52 myworkstation kernel: [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation kernel: [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation kernel: amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(2) succeeded!
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation kernel: [drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation gnome-shell[3628]: amdgpu: amdgpu_cs_query_fence_status failed.
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation gnome-shell[3628]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
Aug 02 22:49:53 myworkstation org.gnome.Totem[7194]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
```

I think it's somehow related to the GPU reset but I wonder what is triggering it. I added these first 3 lines about some update download here because it seems to happen right before. Not sure if it is related.

Graphics: `Radeon RX 590 Series (polaris10, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-78-generic)`

amdgpu related packages I have installed:

```
amdgpu-core/jammy,jammy,now 1:5.4.50403-1538762.22.04 all [installed]
amdgpu-install/jammy,jammy,now 5.4.50403-1538762.22.04 all [installed]
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1/jammy,now 1:2.4.113.50403-1538762.22.04 amd64 [installed]
libdrm-amdgpu-common/jammy,jammy,now 1.0.0.50403-1538762.22.04 all [installed]
libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1/jammy,now 1:2.4.113.50403-1538762.22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm-amdgpu1/jammy-updates,now 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libdrm-amdgpu1/jammy-updates,now 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libdrm2-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:2.4.113.50403-1538762.22.04 amd64 [installed]
libllvm15.0.50403-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:15.0.50403-1538762.22.04 amd64 [installed]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/jammy,now 1:22.3.0.50403-1538762.22.04 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/jammy-updates,now 22.0.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
```